# Using VirtioFS on MacOS for PHP/Symfony application

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

As VirtioFS has been dubbed as attaining almost native filesystem speed, I decided to give docker another try for serving my Symfony 5.4 application in dev local environment on MacOS Ventura, PHP 7.4.

Here is the docker compose configuration:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./var/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.4
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - app-network
  api:
    build: ./docker/php/.
    container_name: api-php
    working_dir: /var/www/api
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/api
    networks:
      - app-network
  openresty:
    image: openresty/openresty:1.21.4.1-0-jammy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/api/public
      - ./master.nginx.docker.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
      - ./api.docker.conf:/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/api.conf
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Where the PHP docker file:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

COPY --from=composer:2.5.8 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/api
```

I can confirm that VitrioFS is enable on my Docker:
[image]

Still it seems that the most basic API requests take 2.5+ seconds, whereas they take less than 300ms when PHP/openresty are running natively. I am getting 4.2s on gRPC Fuse.

Is there something wrong with my configuration, or simply we have been over-promised?

---

Symfony profiler with VirtioFS:

[image: VirtioFS performance]

For the same API call, on native mac:

[image: Native Mac performance]

---

**Further update**

It seems that docker's PHP 7.4 image does not ship with opcache. One must install opcache using `docker-php-ext-install opcache`.

Once I've installed it, performance had a great jump. Still 3-4x slower than native, but much better than 3.5s.

[image: Virtio FS with opcache enabled]

Comment: What does Symfony's profiler tell you about this?

Comment: For a call that took 3.5s: 511ms symfony init, `kernel.request` took 1300ms, `controller.get_callable` 260ms, `controller` 700ms, `kernel.response` 100ms `kernel.terminate` 100ms... basically everything is SUPER slow. What should actually take most time, the database query, took 38ms.

Comment: Actually I've just added the diagrams

Comment: Whenever your set `APP_ENV=prod` in your `.env` file, are you seeing similar results, or is it (way) faster? There are a a lot of [examples](https://t.ly/jyIrs) where `dev` mode is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846995/symfony-4-is-painfully-slow-in-dev) due to the cache rebuild every page request.

Comment: Thanks @Såpe for linking me to that SO question. Using `APP_ENV=prod` did make it quite faster, but then it seems that having `/var/cache/` kept in the volume has almost the same effect without having to fiddle with environments. Posted in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things were needed to get performance 60% as good as native (430ms vs 277ms):

1. Opcache needed to be enabled. It is not enabled by default in docker `php:7.4-fpm` image.

```
  RUN docker-php-ext-install opcache
```

2. Symfony cache does not need to be written back to host ([from question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846995/symfony-4-is-painfully-slow-in-dev)).

```php
// src/Kernel.php

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        // Keep cached files in the docker volume for performance
        if ($this->getEnvironment() === 'test' || $this->getEnvironment() === 'dev') {
            return '/tmp/' . $this->environment;
        } else {
            return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
        }
    }
```

With both of these, I was able to get the following performance from the same API request as in the question.

[image: VirtioFS with Opcache + non-shared cache]

---

One more addition seems to have helped is to not sync `vendor` folder.

I modified the docker compose configuration:

```
  api:
    build: ./docker/php/.
    container_name: api-php
    working_dir: /var/www/api
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/api
      - /var/www/api/vendor
```

And after building the container, I run `docker compose exec api-php php composer install`.